# In-row table page break

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I'm stuck on a problem for hours. I'm using the `tabularx` environment to create a double-column table where the second column takes up several lines. An example of that table is shown [here](http://ge.tt/7MpxtFU/v/0).

Since such a table could not fit in a single page on my document, I've been looking for a way to break it in more pages. Unfortunately, neither the `longtable` nor the `supertabular` package can split the table within a row. Could you please help me find a solution?

In particular, if I can't get this result with a table is there a way to obtain it  with some working alternative (I've already found the `parcolumns` and the `glossary` packages but I would like something that allows me to draw al least a vertical line to separate the two columns.

Comment: I would suggest to set this document not as a table but in a list-like environment where page breaks can happen at any place. If you need to match the look exactly this could be achieved with a custom list environment but it would require some expertise to set it up. To further the discussion, please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) To further Christian's excellent comment, see [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for details on creating a MWE :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an attempt that comes close to what you want using the `mdframed` package.  Because `mdframed` conceives of its frames as single units, I don't know if it's possible to vary the thickness of just the top and bottom lines. Also, since I've used (or abused) the frame title by putting it outside the frame, there's no simple way to get lines to separate the headings.  From the sample document you gave it looks like the format is pretty fixed, so I wrapped each part in either a command or an environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\mdfsetup{frametitlealignment=\hspace{-1in},topline=true, bottomline=false,rightline=false,frametitlebelowskip=-\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\ID}[1]{%
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={ID}]
\texttt{#1}
\end{mdframed}}
\newcommand{\Name}[1]{%
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Name},topline=false]
#1
\end{mdframed}}
\newcommand{\Priority}[1]{%
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Priority},topline=false]
#1
\end{mdframed}}
\newenvironment{Description}{%
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Description}]}
{\end{mdframed}}
\newenvironment{Comments}{%
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Comments}]}
{\end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{A command name}
\ID{F\_Req\_01\_03}
\Name{Password Recovery}
\Priority{Must Have}
\begin{Description}
\kant[1]
\end{Description}
\begin{Comments}
\kant[2-4]
\end{Comments}
\end{document}
```

[image: detail]
[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you Alan, this result is as close as I expected. I'm not so used to LaTeX yet, so customizing things isn't within my reach!

Comment: Sorry @Alan, but I ran into a problem and I can't it figure out. I'm using [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com) to produce my document but it compiles your code with some errors. This is what your code [looks like](http://ge.tt/1rD6NIU/v/0). It seems it don't recognize the `mdfsetup` macro because I got an undefined control sequence for this command. I cannot find any working solution elsewhere. I also checked that ScribTeX uses the full TeXLive environment (so `mdframed` loads perfectly).

Hope you can help me!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any experience with ScribTeX. If you put `\listfiles` as the first line of your document you can see from the log the versions of the packages you used.  My version of `mdframed` is 1.6d.  If the `\mdfsetup` command doesn't work, then it seems that ScribTeX has an older version.